# Where do controllers nested inside of directives get their names from?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In code schools section 4.6 quiz shaping up with angular i noticed the following scenario where the directive controller name seems to map to any controller named in the HTML file.

Here is my Directive in `app.js`:

```
app.directive('productTabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'product-tabs.html',
        controller: function() {
            // move controller inside of the directive 
            this.tab = 1;

            this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
              return this.tab === checkTab;
            };

            this.setTab = function(setTab) {
              this.tab = setTab;
            };
        },
        controllerAs: 'tab'// you need the alias 
    };
});
```

Here is the `index.html`:

```
<product-tabs ng-controller"ProductTab as tab"></product-tabs>
```

However the following `index.html`s work fine to which confuses me.

```
<product-tabs ng-controller"productTab as tab"></product-tabs>
```

Even more confusing is a totally random name for the controller in the `index.html` worked as seen below:

```
<product-tabs ng-controller"foo as tab"></product-tabs>
```

Why does it seem like I can name the Controller almost anything in the HTML regardless of how its declared in the `app.directive` in the JavaScript file? What magic is going on here and is there a topic I should read up on to understand why all of these scenarios work?

I could see if `productTabs` works with all cases and non plural versions but why does it recognize `foo as tab` in the html and somehow realize that maps to the `productTabs` controller?

Comment: I think you're missing the `=` in your ng-controller attribute and that's why it will be ignored. Anyway you don't have to add `ng-controller` in markup for the direcitve to work. It's enough to have `controllerAs` in directive definition object then you can use `tab` inside of the directive template.

Comment: so just having the controllerAs in the directive means i could put the custom directive in my html and it would know about that controller. I dont really need the ng-controller="ViewController as view" .

Comment: Yes, that's right. You don't need it at the directive markup. It's enough to add `<product-tabs></<product-tabs>`. Usually you have a controller at a parent element or if you're using a router `ng-router` or `angular-ui-router` you'll add a controller with `controllerAs` at the view tag.